# Confused About MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, syntax, mutation-observers

So I have been rattling my brain about using the MutationObserver and I haven't made any progress. I've read about it on the W3C site and in the MDN. When reading it in the MDN, everything made sense until the example.

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });   
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

The part I'm having the most trouble with is creating the observer instance, not sure the syntax of what belongs there. Also in the console I've been getting a "TypeError: Value does not implement interface Node."
No matter which examples I've looked at and tried using; replacing the selectors in the example with the desired jQuery selectors (also non-jQ selectors returned the same problem).

Comment: `MutationObserver` is _not_ related to jQuery. The query selector may seems similar to sizzle but they don't share an implementation.

Comment: Do you have an element with the id "some-id"?

Comment: @Frits van Campen I know they're not related, I'm using the jQ library, though and whether I use a jQ selector or not, I get the TypeError message.

Comment: @bfavaretto I stated that I had replaced the selectors with the necessary selectors and was still getting the message.

Comment: The error indicates you're not passing a valid DOM node to `observer.observe`. If you fix that (e.g. by only running that code when the DOM is loaded), the code works (you have to remove the `disconnect` part too, as it removes the observer). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SdFeR/

Comment: @bfavaretto Well thanks for pointing that out, but I do have it within the jQ $(document).ready() method. So I am not sure as to why that would be a problem then. Running it in Firefox's Scratchpad it also gives another error, TypeError: Value not an object (using what's above), but it did log "attributes" after the error.

Comment: Could you reproduce the issues in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Not so much, sorry (makes it difficult I know). The site I'm trying to doing this on use an AJAX request to call the links into the drop menu. The drop menu has an inline style display set to none until you hover a trigger element, which then changes the display and loads the links. The display change is what I'm try to listen for so that I can add some additional links. Using the deprecated DOMAttrModified works, but as I just mentioned, it's deprecated. Taking a closer look at the jsfiddle example you gave, I may have gotten it to work. So thank you for your time :-)

Comment: I have the exact same error, with the exact same example. This is the only post I could find where someone had the same issue with this specific example.

Comment: Oh boy, this is old. If you're using jQuery with it, don't. jQuery nodes do not work with the MutationObserver. You would need to loop through (or get the 0 index if that's all you need) to pass that node to the MutationObserver. Also make sure your target element is what you expect and not null or undefined. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you definitely should not use jQ selectors as they are not Node elements.
second, you must be sure that query selector returns not null.
To make sure try for the first time observer on document.body: it is definitely a Node object.
Something like

```
(
    new MutationObserver(function(mutationEventList){
        console.log(mutationEventList)
    })
)
.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    attributes: true,
    characterData: true
})
```

When you will get familiar with targeting an observer and understand MutationObserverInit options values(they are described not as good as it could) you will be able to work with mutationObserver right.

Comment: is it possible to observe an `{}` for changes with `MutationObserver`??

Answer (score 1):

MutationObserver is a very powerful feature that lets you monitor all types of changes on a node/object in the DOM. In their example, they create the observer here:

```
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });   
});
```

and call it here:

```
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

the target is a node, and the config tells it what to monitor on that node. There are various things you can monitor, and in their example they are monitoring when changes happen to the *attributes*, *childList*, and *characterData*. If any of those items change due to javascript manipulation or user action, *observer* will fire and give you information about what changed and let you take action based on the type of change. It's easiest to see it happen in the console.

To test, make sure you have a valid target selected with:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');
```

Comment: is it possible to observe an `{}` for changes with `MutationObserver`??

Comment: By "{}", do you mean a function? If so, the answer is no. MutationObserver is used to monitor DOM changes.

Comment: MutationObserver is only used to monitor DOM changes. A change inside an object would be a type of event listener.

Answer (score 1):

Simple MutationObserver:

```
<div contentEditable id="myID">EDIT TO FIRE</div>
<script>
let x = new MutationObserver(   function(){ alert('FIRED'); }   );
x.observe(  myID , {subtree:true, characterData:true}  );
</script>
```

See Live: https://jsfiddle.net/bg8k0jmy/